# Вывод значения вложенного списка по индексу

Tags: python, list, индексы

Делаю первые шаги в Pyhton, громко не пинайте пож.
Есть списки, вложенные в список, нужно посчитать среднюю температуру. Вроде всё получается, но никак не удаётся вывести первое значение каждого вложенного списка по циклу. Всю голову сломал, знаю, что просто, но никак не идёт:

```
countries_temperature = [
    ['Thailand', [75.2, 77, 78.8, 73.4, 68, 75.2, 77]],
    ['Germany', [57.2, 55.4, 59, 59, 53.6]],
    ['Russia', [35.6, 37.4, 39.2, 41, 42.8, 39.2, 35.6]],
    ['Poland', [50, 50, 53.6, 57.2, 55.4, 55.4]]
]
print('Средняя температура в странах:')
for i in countries_temperature:
  print([0], '-', round((float(mean(i[1]))-32)/1.8, 1), 'C')
```

Вот этот **print [0]** меня убивает прям, подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Выводится ноль, но, по логике, должно быть название страны...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

всем сорян, расходимся. Вопрос решён. Просто нужно было добавить i перед [0].